# Keep submenu opened when page is refreshed or reloaded

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project in mvc where I have a sidebar in all pages, which is like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center" style="padding-right:2px;" >
  <li>
    <a href="#collapse1" id="btn-1" class="text-center" data-toggle="collapse"><span><b>A</b></span> </a>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center collapse " id="collapse1" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <li><a href="~/A/A-a">A-a</a></li>
      <li><a href="~/A/A-b">A-b</a></li>
      <li><a href="~/A/A-c">A-c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="#collapse2" class="text-center" data-toggle="collapse"><span><b>B</b></span></a>
    <ul id="collapse2" class="collapse nav nav-pills nav-stacked text-center collapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <li><a href="~/B/B-a">B-a</a></li>
      <li><a href="~/B/B-b">B-b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When user clicks on a link like:

```
<li><a href="~/B/B-b">B-b</a></li>
```

Its view (page) shows beside sidebar, but the problem is because of refreshing or reloading page, by clicking on a  tag, submenu collapse and I need to keep it opened.

I searched much in the net and some people suggest using local storage of html5, but all examples are related to nav-tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example about how to save and restore the "expanded" state of Bootstrap's nav menu.
The data to save is `aria-expanded` attribute for each `ul`.

See it on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/eENazo?editors=0011).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //localStorage.clear();   // Uncomment to clear ALL storage.

  // Timer needed because of Bootstrap's animation delay.
  var timer;

  $("ul").on("click",function(e){
    console.log("Click!");

    // Clear previous timer if any.
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){

      // Get expanded states for each ul.
      var expanded=[];
      $("ul").each(function(){
        var thisExpanded = $(this).attr("aria-expanded");
        console.log(thisExpanded);

        if(typeof(thisExpanded) != "undefined"){
          expanded.push( thisExpanded );
        }else{
          expanded.push("undefined");
        }
      });

      // Show it in console.
      var expandedString = JSON.stringify(expanded);
      console.log( expandedString );

      // Save it in Storage.
      localStorage.setItem("ULexpanded",expandedString);
    },600);


  });

  // On load, set ul to previous state.
  console.log("---- On Load.");

  // Parse the string back to an array.
  var previousState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ULexpanded"));
  console.log(previousState);

  // If there is data in locaStorage.
  if(previousState != null){
    console.log("Setting ul states on...");

    $("ul").each(function(index){

      // If the ul was expanded.
      if(previousState[index] == "true"){
        console.log("Index #"+index);
        $(this).addClass("show").attr("aria-expanded", previousState[index]);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. it was really helpful but there is a problem for me that when I click on a li then click on its ul it should be collapse the ul but it expanded again and click on the ul for the second time just move ul belows that ul up but keep open it ils under uls.

Comment: Usually, the `<ul>` or `<ol>` are more like "invisible" containers and users click on the `<li>`. If you set an event handler on a `<ul>`, make sure the `<li>` events do not propagate up... Triggering 2 handlers. Look for [`.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).